# LibGDX Desktop launch error

Tags: graphics, libgdx, box2d

I have a game in Libgdx. It will now not run on the desktop version, or on android. When I run  Main.java as desktop application, it sends these errors.. I will also post my code. Thanks.

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLCommon
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
    at com.ahewdev.spacepace.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GLCommon
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Desktop - Main.java code

```
package com.ahewdev.spacepace;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.ahewdev.spacepace.SpacePace;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.setup.resources.desktop.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "spacepace";
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 320;
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        new LwjglApplication(new SpacePace(), cfg);
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
[image: Here is my Build path]

Comment: The Main.java code seems fine, the problem seems to be with the projet setup - some parts of libGDX missing or not linked properly...

Comment: I agree, can you show us your build path ?

Comment: @Nizil Thanks for the help, just added my build path.

Comment: I don't see any prob'... Did you setup the project with the setup-ui ? I suppose your using an old libGDX version, maybe you can try to use the last release (1.0.0+) which use Gradle to handle the project.

Comment: @Nizil ok I'll play around with it and try to update. Thanks!